# Removing Hystrix Circuit

Tags: hystrix

In a Java application, I have a situation where I need a circuit for a period of time. Using a Hystrix Dashboard, listening to the /hystrix.stream, I'm able to see the circuit created just fine. The problem is when the circuit is not longer needed, it still shows up in the dashboard. I'd like to just delete the circuit. The dashboard is getting cluttered with circuits that are no longer relevant. Any ideas?